# Can't chance locale setting of app downloaded from play store

Tags: java, locale

I can change app language on popup menu item click if it is debug but it doesn't work properly if it is downloaded from play store. For example when i press button to convert Italy, it converts to English.

Here my codes are;

```java
String[] lang_codes=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.lang_codes);
String[] languages=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.languages);

public void  select_language(View v)
   {
       final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(BirimCevirici2.this, v);
       languages=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.languages);
       for (String s : languages) {
           popup.getMenu().add(s);
       }
       popup.show();
       popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
           public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

               for (int j = 0; j < languages.length; j++) {
                   if(item.getTitle().toString().equals(languages[j]))
                   {
                       updateResources(lang_kod[j],j);
                   }
               }
               return true;
           }
       });
   }

private  void updateResources(String lang,int i) {
       Locale locale = new Locale(lang); // where 'hi' is Language code, set this as per your Spinner Item selected
       Locale.setDefault(locale);
       Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
       config.locale = locale;
       getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
               getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
       setContentView(R.layout.birim_cevir);
       languages=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.languages);
   }
```

values xml file contains;

```java
<string-array name="lang_codes">
       <item> en</item>
       <item> de</item>
       <item> fr</item>
       <item> es</item>
       <item> it</item>
       <item> pt</item>
       <item> ru</item>
       <item> tr</item>
   </string-array>


//Array below is different for every language in their xml files
<string-array name="languages">
       <item> English</item>
       <item> German</item>
       <item> French</item>
       <item> Spanish</item>
       <item> Italian</item>
       <item> Portuguese</item>
       <item> Russian</item>
       <item> Turkish</item>
   </string-array>
```

[Here my string and arrays xml file SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbKjj.png)

Note : I added code below to application and all activities in AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|layoutDirection|locale"
```